# I am having trouble with running java Threads, It would only run once

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, try-catch

I am designing a chat application using sockets. this is the code for reading data from server.
It compiles just fine but the thread only runs only once. please help me out.

```
public void reader() {
    Thread read=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                while(true) {
                    if(in.readLine()!=null) {
                        System.out.println("Recived Message: "+ in.readLine());
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    };

    read.setPriority(10);
    read.start();
}
```

Ok I tried this code and it doesnt work as well

```
public void reader()
{
    Thread u=new Thread()
        {
        public void run()
            {
            try {
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("ssss");
                if(input.readLine()!=null)
                {
                    String message=input.readLine();
                    System.out.println("SERVER:"+message);
                }
                else{
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }

            } 
            }
            catch (IOException e)

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

    };
    try{
    u.start();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

And the output i get is
sss
just once. but i have a while loop that is always true. why doesnt ir run infinitely?

Comment: `catch(Exception e){}` - you are shooting yourself in the foot on purpose. Stop doing that.

Comment: process is still running in your console , while(true)

Comment: Why are you discarding every second line you read?

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block to see is there any exception.

Comment: It compiles fine but the while loop only runs only one time

Comment: You read input.readLine() twice but use it only once. So, if you ahve 2 messages, your loop will run only once.

Answer (score 1):

*(can't comment due to low reputation...)*

Better read line this way:

```
String line = "";
while( (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Recived Message: " + line);
}
```

*PS: Take care, you are calling 2 times readLine()*

Comment: I tried this way too. but still the while loop runs only once

Comment: then readLine is just reading 1 line or is returning null after that. Maybe printing the catch block could give you some tips: catch(Exception e){ e.getMessage()}

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is remove the catch and the IOException

If you need a Thread like that more than once you should consider to encapsulate it in a class.

Like seen here:

```
public class Foo extends Thread
{
    public Foo()
    {
        super("Foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        while(!isInterrupted())
        {
            System.out.println("Still running");

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Thread foo = new Foo();
        foo.start();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can consider implementing the Runnable Interface as it is seen to be the preferred way of handling with Threads in Java.

For further information why it is please have a look at:

["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread?lq=1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You call readLine twice and in each call it fetches the next line so the first is reading the line and the second has nothing to read so it stuck

Comment: I fixed this problem. But still the while loop is not running more than once